# eBay API throws Invalid ShipToLocation error when adding new listing

Tags: xml, ebay-api

I am trying to list new products on eBay's UK site using their API, but my request results in a `Invalid ShipToLocation` error (full error message below). I am fetching data from my database and trying to send it to eBay.

Here is the request XML:

```
<AddFixedPriceItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
     <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>Ebay TOken</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
    <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
    <Version>551</Version>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
    <Item>
        <Site>UK</Site><PrimaryCategory><CategoryID>164306</CategoryID></PrimaryCategory><StartPrice currencyID="GBP">120.99</StartPrice><BuyItNowPrice>0</BuyItNowPrice>       
        <BestOfferDetails>
            <BestOfferEnabled>false</BestOfferEnabled>
        </BestOfferDetails>
        <Country>GB</Country>
        <Currency>GBP</Currency>
        <DispatchTimeMax>10</DispatchTimeMax>
        <ListingDuration>Days_3</ListingDuration>
        <ListingType>FixedPriceItem</ListingType>
        <PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>
        <PayPalEmailAddress>abc@gmail.com</PayPalEmailAddress>
        <PictureDetails><PhotoDisplay>PicturePack</PhotoDisplay><PictureURL>http://i.ebayimg.sandbox.ebay.com/00/s/NTUwWDU1MA==/z/pRQAAOSwZDVUXafi/$_1.JPG?set_id=8800005007</PictureURL></PictureDetails>
        <Location><![CDATA[SURAT, GUJARAT]]></Location><Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <ReturnPolicy>
          <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
          <RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>
          <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_14</ReturnsWithinOption>
          <Description>If you are not satisfied, return the item for refund.</Description>
          <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
        </ReturnPolicy>
        <ShippingDetails>
        <ShippingServiceOptions>
          <ShippingService>UK_StandardShippingFromOutside</ShippingService>
          <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="GBP">0.0</ShippingServiceCost>
          <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
          <ExpeditedService>false</ExpeditedService>
          <ShippingTimeMin>5</ShippingTimeMin>
          <ShippingTimeMax>10</ShippingTimeMax>
          <FreeShipping>true</FreeShipping>
        </ShippingServiceOptions>

        <InternationalShippingServiceOption>
          <ShippingService>UK_SellersStandardInternationalRate</ShippingService>
          <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="GBP">0.0</ShippingServiceCost>
          <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
          <ShipToLocation>Americas</ShipToLocation>
          <ShipToLocation>CA</ShipToLocation>
          <ShipToLocation>GB</ShipToLocation>
          <ShipToLocation>AU</ShipToLocation>
          <ShipToLocation>Europe</ShipToLocation>
          <ShipToLocation>Asia</ShipToLocation>
          <ShipToLocation>CN</ShipToLocation>
          <ShipToLocation>MX</ShipToLocation>
          <ShipToLocation>DE</ShipToLocation>
          <ShipToLocation>JP</ShipToLocation>
          <ShipToLocation>BR</ShipToLocation>
          <ShipToLocation>FR</ShipToLocation>
          <ShipToLocation>RU</ShipToLocation>
        </InternationalShippingServiceOption>
        <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType><SellerExcludeShipToLocationsPreference>true</SellerExcludeShipToLocationsPreference>
        </ShippingDetails>
        <ShipToLocations>Worldwide</ShipToLocations><RegionID>0</RegionID><ShippingTermsInDescription>True</ShippingTermsInDescription>
        <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
    </Item>
</AddFixedPriceItemRequest>
```

I get the following error as response for the above request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AddFixedPriceItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2014-11-08T12:54:21.441Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Failure</Ack>
  <Errors>
    <ShortMessage>Invalid ShipToLocation.</ShortMessage>
    <LongMessage>Some of the ShipTo locations provided are not valid for this site. They have been dropped from your listing.</LongMessage>
    <ErrorCode>17520</ErrorCode>
    <SeverityCode>Warning</SeverityCode>
    <ErrorParameters ParamID="0">
      <Value>&lt;InternationalShippingServiceOptions&gt;</Value>
    </ErrorParameters>
    <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
  </Errors>
  <Version>891</Version>
  <Build>E891_UNI_API5_17051033_R1</Build>
</AddFixedPriceItemResponse>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<LongMessage>` tag content from the response XML is self explanatory

> Some of the ShipTo locations provided are not valid for this site. They have been dropped from your listing.

Have a look at `<ShipToLocation>` tags from the request XML

```
<ShipToLocation>Americas</ShipToLocation>
<ShipToLocation>CA</ShipToLocation>
<ShipToLocation>GB</ShipToLocation>
<ShipToLocation>AU</ShipToLocation>
<ShipToLocation>Europe</ShipToLocation>
<ShipToLocation>Asia</ShipToLocation>
<ShipToLocation>CN</ShipToLocation>
<ShipToLocation>MX</ShipToLocation>
<ShipToLocation>DE</ShipToLocation>
<ShipToLocation>JP</ShipToLocation>
<ShipToLocation>BR</ShipToLocation>
<ShipToLocation>FR</ShipToLocation>
<ShipToLocation>RU</ShipToLocation>
```

According to [eBay API Documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/best-match-item-details/CallRef/Enums/shipToLocationList.html), `BR` and `RU` are not valid. Try to remove `<ShipToLocation>BR</ShipToLocation>` and `<ShipToLocation>RU</ShipToLocation>`
 from the request XML.

Comment: I have remove <ShipToLocation>BR</ShipToLocation> and <ShipToLocation>RU</ShipToLocation> but its not working.

Comment: Can you try to have only `<ShipToLocation>Americas</ShipToLocation>` in the request XML and see if it works?

Comment: Then other errors are occurs: Short Messgae: Condition is not applicable.. Long MessageCondition is not applicable for this category.

Comment: Try to make a call to [GeteBayDetails](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/GeteBayDetails.html#GeteBayDetails) with `DetailName` set to `ShippingLocationDetails`, then in the response iterate through each ShippingLocationDetails element and read in the value of ShippingLocation, it should show the valid values for `<ShipToLocation>` tag.